# Can ransomware virus be removed from an affected PC?

Tags: ransomware

I have had a ransomware attack that has only encrypted some files. Is there any way to find the virus and prevent it from encrypting more files?

Comment: It can be removed but the damage done by it may or may not be recovered.

Comment: So, how can I remove it?

Comment: As is true for most host compromises...your best bet is back up the data you have left and re-image the machine.

Comment: Well the first thing you need to do is pull the plug immediately.

Comment: How can you remove it? It depends on the type of the ransomware. There ate tools created for specific type of ransomware.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a malware removal forum.

Comment: You may require assistance to remove ransomware from your PC. You can discuss your problem in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz).

Comment: @DarkMatter Can I trust the files that are not encrypted? at least asking about the non-executable files (docs, images, ...etc). And what about the executable files? Is there any guarantee that the virus will not be executed one I try to install the programs?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with a ransomware is to take out the plug immediately and remove the hard disk. You should always have a backup of the hard disk. Removing ransomware from a system is not that easy and a tedious task. The best way is to abandon the system and take a back up of all your data.

Comment: Why remove the hard disk after you unplug the power? Abandoning the system is not necessary if you can format and reinstall.